# Series expansion of positive real numbers. Arbitrary expansion

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a = \lbrace a_1,a_2,\dots\rbrace$ be an arbitrary fixed sequence of integers greater than one. One can prove that every $0\leq x<1$ has an expansion of the form

$$
x = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{x_j}{a_1 a_2\dots a_j} \quad (1)
$$

where $x_j$ is a sequence of integers such that $0 \leq x_j <a_j$ for all $j$.

My question is, how do I find necessary and sufficient conditions that two distinct expansions converge to the same number? Incidentally, I have never understood quite well how to find such conditions. However, I know that an if and ony if statement is equivalent.

In any case, a necessary condition must be that, if $x = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{y_j}{b_1 b_2\dots b_j}$ is another such expansion, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>m\geq N$ it must be

$$
|S^x_n-S^y_m|<\epsilon
$$

where $S^x_n$, $S^y_m$ are the partial sums of $(1)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{y_j}{a_1\dots a_j}$. Is this correct? Are there more conditions?

Comment: What you say is correct. But it doesn't seem like a "real" answer to the question of when the two sums agree; it's more or less just the _definition_ of "the two sums agree".

Answer (score 1):

### A useful equality

For any integer $k\geqslant 2$ :
$\displaystyle \sum_{j=k}^{+\infty} \dfrac{a_{j}-1}{a_1a_2\ldots a_j}= \sum_{j=k}^{+\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{a_1a_2\ldots a_{j-1}}-\dfrac{1}{a_1a_2\ldots a_j}\right)=    \dfrac{1}{a_1a_2\ldots a_{k-1}}$

### A necessary condition

Suppose now that a real $x$ has two expansions:
$\ x=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\alpha_i}{a_1a_2\ldots a_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\beta_i}{a_1a_2\ldots a_i}$

Let $\ k=\min\{i\in \mathbb N^* \ : \ \alpha_i \neq \beta_i\}$.

If $\alpha_k>\beta_k$, we can write:
$\displaystyle \dfrac{\alpha_k-\beta_k}{a_1a_2\ldots a_k} = \sum_{i=k+1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\beta_i-\alpha_i}{a_1a_2\ldots a_i}$

It's then necessary that:
$(\alpha_k-\beta_k = 1) \ $ and $\ \left(\forall i \geqslant k+1 \ , \ (\beta_i,\alpha_i) = (a_i-1,0) \right)$

So, $x$ has a finite expansion    $\displaystyle x =\sum_{i=1}^k \dfrac{\alpha_i}{a_1a_2 \ldots a_i}$

### This condition is sufficient

Not difficult to prove $\ldots$

Comment: Shouldn't you need to change the set $\lbrace a_1,\dots\rbrace$ in order to have another equivalent expansion?

Comment: If we can change the set $\{a_1,\ldots\}$, any real $x\in ]0,1[$ would have an infinity of expansions ...

Comment: But that's what the expansion is about. It can be any set and still give $x$. The exercise is to my understading this, find conditions of two arbitrary expansions of $x$ .